# Pie Chart on a Scatter Plot

Tags: javascript, charts, scatter, pie-chart

https://www.dropbox.com/s/mcmzn0t0hz4s2x7/pieChartScatterPlot.png

Hi. Please have a look at the above link. Its a scatter plot basically. But, these are not just the dots. Instead of dots, we have pie charts(drill down). i.e, the dots are further divided into another category thus forming a pie chart. Please tell me if this type of chart can be created using any javascript library. If yes, then how? Please be specific. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you find any graphing library that can support both scatter and pie charts, and allows for custom event handlers (d3 is good for this) http://d3js.org/. Then show just the scatter graph, on click of a node popover the relevant pie chart